# Consequences of International date line on Jum'ah (friday) prayer

Tags: jumuah, travelling

When flying across the international date line, it is possible to experience Jum'ah twice a week. For example, using [JQ3](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?id=304355594&airlineCode=JQ&flightNumber=3), one can leave Sydney on Friday 6pm  and arrive in Honolulu on Friday 7am. So he can travel after performing Jum'ah and when he arrive, it is time for Jum'ah again. Has there been any ruling on whether there is obligation to pray twice, or is it ok to choose either Friday?

Bonus: Conversely, it is also possible to completely miss a Friday noon by travelling in the opposite direction, e.g. with [JQ4](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?airline=&flightNumber=JQ4)  one can leave Hawaii on Thursday morning and arrive in Sydney Friday afternoon, even though it's just a 10 hours' flight

Comment: Jumma is not a mandatory (farz) prayer, so you can skip it if you have already prayed it.

Comment: @goto, Jumma is a mandatory (farz) prayer.

Comment: @Muslim I think he means Jummah is not fardh on a traveller.

Answer (score 1):

Once an obligation is fulfilled, it is lifted from you. You can join in the prayer if you wish as a *nafl* prayer, but it's your choice. As for travelling the other way, you are a traveller and the obligation is lifted anyway.